# Rare not reproducible crash related to UIKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash, uikit

I have a random-looking crash related to UIKit and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Does anyone see a familiar pattern here or do you think this might be a random OS-related crash? Is there a way to find out which Buttons or UI-elements were involved here?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35260f78 objc_msgSend + 15
1   UIKit                               0x312363d7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) superview] + 50
2   UIKit                               0x31239abb -[UIView nextResponder] + 82
3   UIKit                               0x31354011 forwardTouchMethod + 36
4   UIKit                               0x3124f97d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 400
5   UIKit                               0x3124f319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380
6   UIKit                               0x31235695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
7   UIKit                               0x313e762f __42-[UIApplication _cancelTouches:withEvent:]_block_invoke_0 + 54
8   UIKit                               0x312a5d0d -[UIApplication _cancelTouches:withEvent:includingGestures:notificationBlock:] + 544
9   UIKit                               0x312a5ae9 -[UIApplication _cancelTouches:withEvent:] + 84
10  UIKit                               0x31234eb1 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5688
11  GraphicsServices                    0x33c7722b PurpleEventCallback + 882
12  CoreFoundation                      0x37535523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
13  CoreFoundation                      0x375354c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
14  CoreFoundation                      0x37534313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
15  CoreFoundation                      0x374b74a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
16  CoreFoundation                      0x374b736d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
17  GraphicsServices                    0x33c76439 GSEventRunModal + 136
18  UIKit                               0x31263cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
```

Comment: I also tend to experience 'random' crashes especially using UIAlertView. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: [So you crashed in objc_msgSend()](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html) - an older post; but may have some diagnostic tips to use/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/919545